# Problem to migrate an angular application to microfrontend

Tags: angular, micro-frontend, angular-standalone-components

I'm trying to migrate my angular application to microfrontends

Here is my remote:

```
const mfe = require('@angular-architects/module-federation/webpack');
const ModuleFederationPlugin = require('webpack/lib/container/ModuleFederationPlugin')

const commonConfigDep = { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto', eager: true }

module.exports = {
  output: {
    uniqueName: 'mfe1',
    publicPath: 'auto',
    scriptType: 'text/javascript'
  },
  optimization: {
    runtimeChunk: false,
  },
  plugins: [
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      name: 'mfe1',
      library: { type: 'var', name: 'mfe1' },
      filename: 'remoteEntry.js',
      exposes: {
        './routes': './src/app/app.routes.ts', // this application are full standalone, i don't have ngmodules to export
      },
      shared: mfe.share({
        "@angular/core": commonConfigDep,
        "@angular/common": commonConfigDep,
        "@angular/router": commonConfigDep
      }),
    }),
  ]
};
```

And the app.routing.module of the shell application:

```
import { loadRemoteModule } from '@angular-architects/module-federation';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'test',
    loadChildren: () => loadRemoteModule({
      type: 'module',
      remoteEntry: 'http://localhost:4201/test/remoteEntry.js',
      exposedModule: './routes',
    }).then(m => m.ROUTES)
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

When i navigate to the page /test on shell the error throw on console:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: container.init is not a function
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: container.get is not a function
```

Anyone can help? Thx